Static routing not working on ISP router F6600R
Since I'm not the best at networking, I need an answer more as a confirmation whether I'm crazy or dumb.
I've got a ISP router ZTE F6600R, and I've got a server running a VM with RouterOS.
ISP router subnet is 192.168.1.0/24, and RouterOS has 10.20.22.0/24, and its WAN is 192.168.1.6.
In my ISP router config, there is a "Static routes" list, in which I add my static route, and... it doesn't work. Whatever I do, tracert always shows that it goes out the router towards some upstream router, since am behind CGNAT. But I don't think that's important in this situation. Or maybe it is? That's why I come asking for help.
Now, the question is, am I just crazy or is there some functionality I don't understand.
If I add manually static routes to my devices (windows for example), and point it to the RouterOS and specify the subnets and a gateway, it all works, therefore I believe I've set it all up properly, but I can't get the ISP router to do its job. ISP screenshot
All the routes are preset, I cant change them, the only one I added is the second down at the bottom of the page. I tried all the options, I tried other subnets, nothing works. Is there some priority, or something similar so whatever I do wont work because ISP set it like that or?
If you need any screenshots or configs or whatever, please ask. I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but I want to know more.
EDIT:Larger image of static routing menu

This definitely looks like it should work. The only thing that makes sense to me might be that settings need to be "applied" somehow (one would think the apply button would be all you need, but who knows what weird things people do). If you reboot the router, are your added routes still there? It's certainly possible that your ISP has modified the firmware on your router to exclude those routes, but that would be bizarre to me.

Could you share the other sections under "static routing" in your screenshot? One would assume all the same information is replicated in the routing table, but there might be a clue in there

Yes, I tried to reboot after doing changes, and it still doesn't work. I am still digging for a solution, maybe there is some option am missing or something... I also have L2TP options so I might just connect it like site-to-site tunnel (this is so dumb and overcomplicated) or maybe a VLAN, but idk if the router supports it. I found some VLAN options, but it only specifies a port and a VLAN but idk where to add an interface or something like that... and as I said, Im not that good at networking
EDIT: also added a pic you requested

What happens if you disconnect the router from the internet?

Also If you can get a shell, you might be able to learn a bit more about what the routing table is doing. I don't know if it's possible to get a shell on your device, it used to be reasonably common but I haven't used a consumer router in about 10 years

@RobM I tried to SSH and telnet into it, both said connection refused, and I cant find any options on it to allow it, got any hint?
In the help area of the static routing it says
"1. If network address and subnet mask are both 0.0.0.0, this configuration will be a default routing, which is effective for any destination address.

If WAN connection and gateway are both configured, please ensure that the gateway can be reached through this WAN connection."
I tried changing the default route to be for default subnet and to go the upstream GW I see presented, but it did nothing...


-> in hope to try to evade that "this configuration will be a default routing, which is effecting for any destination address", but its kinda dumb, whats the point of routing if youll just shoot everything through one hole? Maybe im understanding it poorly

When the address and mask are both 0.0.0.0 that is the default route, in the sense that it's the route that's used when no other route matches. I don't think you're misunderstanding, by all means this should be working. My only idea is that the router doesn't want to forward a packet back into the same network that it came from, but I've never seen that behavior either, just a guess

The ISP router likely prioritizes its default routes, ignoring your static route. Manually adding routes on devices works because it bypasses the router’s logic, confirming your setup is fine. If the ISP router doesn't allow full customization of routing or enforces higher-priority default routes, you might be limited by its functionality.
Check router settings. Some routers allow you to adjust route priorities or override default routes.

It doesn't make sense that the router would have a page for adding routes that it ignores, and it would violate the whole premise of a routing table to prioritize a /0 route over a /24 route

Yea, adding a static route to my windows routing table tells it where to send stuff so it doesn't have to ask the router, ik, but as the comment above says, it's quite dumb to have it as an option, and to show it in the router routing table, just for it to not work..? But then again, maybe the firmware was edited by the ISP and it just displays stuff but it doesn't take it into account?
